# Issue running command in cronjob but works as a regular command

Tags: terminal, script, cron

I'm trying to run a `yt-dlp` command inside a cronjob but am having trouble. The command runs fine when run as a regular terminal command but inside a cronjob it fails. I've included an image of the cronjob and the mail output. Thank you in advance for the help!

Cronjob: `yt-dlp --cookies /Users/admin/Movies/YoutubeCookies.txt --download-archive FILE --output “/Users/admin/Movies/Youtube\ Backup” -f bestvideo*+bestaudio/best “[https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL)”`

Mail output:

```
Subject: Cron <kylenadler@kyles-mbp-2> sudo yt-dlp --cookies /Users/admin/Movies/YoutubeCookies.txt --download-archive FILE -P /Users/admin/Movies/YoutubeBackup --write-auto-subs --sub-format "srt" -f "bv+ba/b" "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL"
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=admin>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=admin>
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2022 10:08:00 -0500 (EST)
```

Comment: How does it fail - and please cut and paste text output as text not images so that we can read them

Comment: Please put details in the question not as comments

Comment: Updated, thank you for the help I'm new to posting here!

Comment: The playlist URL is in markdown format, is this what the command expects?

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved this way:

1. Run `echo $PATH` to see your path while logged into the system.
2. Add the `PATH=X` at the top of your `crontab` file with `X` being your path from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that  yt-dlp  is not on your PATH in crontab but it is in the terminal.

To see look at the output of `echo $PATH`  and `which yt-dip` in Terminal

The quick fix is pput the full path for yt-dip in the crontab.

However that might not be sufficient if internals of yt-dip  rely on the PATH. In this case create a shell script that sets the $PATH and then runs the program.

Comment: When you say full path what do you mean?

Comment: the equivalent to which yt-dip - ie the directory the executable is in and the executable name so that the ssystem can find the executable without looking at $PATH

Comment: If I installed using homebrew how can I find the path for the directory?

Comment: See the second command in my answer

Comment: thank you for the help that worked! follow up issue, when running the command inside the cronjob it is outputting the video and audio but running the command in a regular terminal it outputs both combined as it should

Comment: I do think ffmpeg is required for both to be merged but when I include that path as well it still doesn't merge correct `45 14 * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/yt-dlp /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg  yt-dlp --cookies /Users/admin/Movies/YoutubeCookies.txt --download-archive FILE3 -P /Users/admin/Movies/YoutubeBackup --write-auto-subs --sub-format "srt" -f bv+ba/b "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=LL"`